# How can I select several columns with specific title

Tags: r

I have a data set containing columns with various elements and their error

(e.g. Pb, Pb.error, Cu, Cu.error, Zn, Zn.error, Fe, Fe.error).

how can I select multiple columns by their names (I want to select Pb, Pb.error, Zn, Zn.error for example)?

I have tried:

```
subset(myData, select = (grep("Pb", dataTitle)))
```

that works fine for one element and its error (I could select Pb and Pb error).

but it does not work for multiple elements and their errors:

```
subset(myData, select = (grep("Pb", dataTitle)|grep("Zn", dataTitle)))
```

the code above prints all the elements I have (i.e. it does not managed to select any of the specific column). I am very confused and do not know the reason behind it.

I also tried

```
subset(myData, select = c("Pb","Pb.Error","Zn","Zn.Error"))
```

That perfectly works for me, but I was wondering if I could make it simpler, because I believe "Pb" and "Pb.error" could be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer 1 min after posing this question.
It is easy if I just use "Pb|Zn" in grep function

```
subset(myData, select(grep("Pb|Zn", dataTitle)))
```

That works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works too, unless you are specifically trying to call the errors columns by their association to their respective data columns:

```
myData[,c("Pb","Pb.Error","Zn","Zn.Error")]
```

Comment: Yeah, that works fine, but there are actually around 10 different elements to quote, so I was trying to avoid direct quote them. But thank you for your answer! that is more neat than mine code

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way with a few more restrictions on the regex:

```
df <- tibble(
  Pb = NA, Pb.error = NA, Cu = NA, Cu.error = NA, Zn = NA, Zn.error = NA, Fe = NA, Fe.error = NA
)

df[, grepl("^(Pb|Zn).*$", names(df))]
```